# Table layout xml for leaderboard template - Android

Tags: android, android-layout, android-recyclerview, recyclerview-layout

I'm trying to create a layout for a user leader-board but I don't know how to make every "row" equal in proportion.

Here's the list of users:
[image: link to image]

And this is the code of the child layout (that populates a recyclerview):

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:id="@+id/topUsersLeaderboardItem_layout"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:weightSum="12"
android:orientation="horizontal"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/margin_extra_small"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/margin_extra_small">


<TextView
    android:id="@+id/topUsersLeaderboardItem_position"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="0"
    android:paddingStart="@dimen/margin_small"
    android:textColor="@color/colorBlack"
    android:layout_weight="2"
    android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
    android:textSize="@dimen/font_size_small"/>

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="8">
    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/topUsersLeaderboardItem_layoutPicUser"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/topUsersLeaderboardItem_userIcon"
            android:layout_width="50dp"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:src="@drawable/circular_profile"
            app:srcCompat="@drawable/circular_profile" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/topUsersLeaderboardItem_userInitial"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal|center"
            android:text="U"
            android:textSize="@dimen/font_size_medium"/>
    </RelativeLayout>
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/topUsersLeaderboardItem_username"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
        android:text="uername"
        android:textColor="@color/colorBlack"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/topUsersLeaderboardItem_layoutPicUser"
        android:textSize="@dimen/font_size_small"/>
</RelativeLayout>


<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/topUsersLeaderboardItem_scoreLayout"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
    android:layout_weight="2"
    android:gravity="end">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/topUsersLeaderboardItem_score"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:text="150"
        android:textSize="@dimen/font_size_small"
        android:textColor="@color/colorBlack" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/topUsersLeaderboardItem_starImage"
        android:layout_width="30dp"
        android:layout_height="30dp"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="false"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/margin_small"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/topUsersLeaderboardItem_score"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_star_yellow_24dp"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_star_yellow_24dp" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

As you can see from the picture, the space taken by the numbers on the left increases when I would like it to be fixed. Is there a way to make this sort of "table layout"? Thanks everybody!

Comment: You can use table layout  https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/grid.html, or read on how can you align the views inside a layout.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

please use this

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:id="@+id/topUsersLeaderboardItem_layout"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:weightSum="12"
android:orientation="horizontal"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/margin_extra_small"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/margin_extra_small">


<TextView
    android:id="@+id/topUsersLeaderboardItem_position"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="0"
    android:paddingStart="@dimen/margin_small"
    android:textColor="@color/colorBlack"
    android:layout_weight="2"
    android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
    android:textSize="@dimen/font_size_small"/>

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
    android:layout_weight="8">
    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/topUsersLeaderboardItem_layoutPicUser"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/topUsersLeaderboardItem_userIcon"
            android:layout_width="50dp"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:src="@drawable/circular_profile"
            app:srcCompat="@drawable/circular_profile" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/topUsersLeaderboardItem_userInitial"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal|center"
            android:text="U"
            android:textSize="@dimen/font_size_medium"/>
    </RelativeLayout>
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/topUsersLeaderboardItem_username"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
        android:text="uername"
        android:textColor="@color/colorBlack"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/topUsersLeaderboardItem_layoutPicUser"
        android:textSize="@dimen/font_size_small"/>
</RelativeLayout>


<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/topUsersLeaderboardItem_scoreLayout"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
    android:layout_weight="2">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/topUsersLeaderboardItem_score"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:text="150"
        android:textSize="@dimen/font_size_small"
        android:textColor="@color/colorBlack" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/topUsersLeaderboardItem_starImage"
        android:layout_width="30dp"
        android:layout_height="30dp"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="false"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/margin_small"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/topUsersLeaderboardItem_score"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_star_yellow_24dp"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_star_yellow_24dp" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 1):

Actually, it is because of `android:layout_width="wrap_content"` 
of first TextView, give it some predefined value like `android:layout_width="10dp"`. Don't forget to remove gravity from TextView.